# BlackBerry OS 6 App Dev

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde, blackberry-webworks

When developing a application for iOS that pulls in a web site, you have a very simple web app wrapper that as far as I know acts like an `iframe`, pulls in the web site and boom - you have an app.

My understanding is that if done this way you are using a "stripped down" Safari to view the web site in a "app" as it is a web wrapper.

When developing an app for BB OS6, is it the same concept? If I develop a wrapper that says *"go fetch site x and display it in this app"* is it going to use BB OS6 default browser APIs to render said site?

Also is there links to said API?

Comment: Create a webworks application. It simply takes a url and wraps it up into an application. The url may be either local (bundled with the app) or a website.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a container to display Web content I'd highly recommend you use Webworks (or cordova for cross platform) as opposed to Java. WebWorks already creates and sets up the bf2 for you in a tested and proven way.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for iOS would be the BlackBerry [BrowserField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html).

If you want some examples of how to use it, I recommend installing the [BlackBerry Eclipse plugin](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse/).  That will install in Eclipse the full BlackBerry Java SDK (e.g. version 6.0, 7.0, etc.), which comes with lots of sample code.  From Eclipse, you can then

**Import... -> BlackBerry -> Import BlackBerry Samples -> BrowserField2Demo**.

Note that you want the **BrowserField2Demo**, not BrowserFieldDemo!

Or, you can go directly to the github site [with BlackBerry sample code](https://github.com/blackberry/JDE-Samples/tree/master/com/rim/samples/device/browser/browserfield2demo).